# Taking samples (indexA to indexB) from a Circular array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array

```
var a=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15];
```

The way I am using this array is that it's start is it's end, like this:

```
             0
        1        15
     2              14
    3                13
   4                  12
    5                11
     6              10
        7         9
             8
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer

The array length is also a much longer number

I want to take samples from it, like, take from an index till another index and each time to take `n` items counting back.

so if the index you wanted to get was 2, and `n` was 3 you would get

```
a[0],a[1],a[2] // 0,1,2
```

might be done with slice or might be better to gather them by a loop..

but what if the index I want is 1 or 0 then how would I get the last parts if `n` can change at any time

What would be a easy way to do this?

---

```
var a=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

var index=1;

var n=4;

var i=[n,0];

var b=[];

while(i[0]--){

    b.unshift(
        a[index-i[1]]!==undefined?a[index-i[1]]:a[a.length-Math.abs(index-i[1])]
        );

    i[1]+=1;

    }

console.log(b);  // [9, 10, 0, 1]
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like you've made an attempt yet to solve your own problem. If you have, then please show us what you've done.

Comment: I didn't want to turn this into a *this vs that* question

Answer (score 2):

I would do it with `.slice()` this way:

```
var a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

function getFromCircArr(arr, i, n) {
    var d = i + 1 - n;
    return d < 0 ?  arr.slice(d).concat(arr.slice(0, i + 1)) : arr.slice(d, i + 1);
};

getFromCircArr(a, 2, 3); // --> [0, 1, 2]
getFromCircArr(a, 1, 4); // --> [9, 10, 0, 1]
```